# Going from a PVC Sched 40 1-1/2" PIPE to a 1/2" Poly Combination Elbow

Tags: plumbing, pipe, pvc, fitting

I'm new here. I have a plumbing question. I'm not a plumber by any means.

I'm trying to put together a small DYI project as a Xmas gift for a couple of family members and a couple of friends.

Its a Liquor Dispenser, similar to the ones shown below.

[image]

I'm having trouble finding the correct piece to make it work. I live in a small town so my options are limited as far as going to a store to buy pieces, but I thought with a bit of coaching from the more experienced people online, I might be able to buy the missing piece of the puzzle from an online supplier.

**THE PROTOTYPE**

I'll show you what I have done so far.

I have built a functional working prototype, but it is made with ABS parts.

[image]

I figured its probably not such a great idea to give these as gifts to people I know. They might not be so happy when the leeched chemicals from the ABS pipe cause growths on the sides of their neck.

No worries, It was just a prototype to see if it would work.

For that I used from top to bottom:

1. Spigot x Slip Joint ABS "P" Trap Adapter (works great as a bottle support)
2. 1-1/2" ABS Coupling
3. 1-1/2" x 1/2" ABS Dishwasher Bushing
4. 1/2" Poly Combination Elbow
5. 1/2" ID x 5/8 OD Nylon hose w/ clamps (not shown in photo)
6. 1/2" Insert x 1/4" Male Pipe Thread Brass Hose Connector
7. 1/2" Female Thread x Male Garden Hose Thread 1/2" Sediment Faucet, with Flange

**THE SECOND ATTEMPT**

Now I am trying the recreate that, using PVC parts. As you will see, I've run into a problem which I have circled in red. I'm not able to come up with a solution with the parts provided at any of the local hardware stores.

Here is how it looks so far:
[image]

From top to bottom I have:

1. About 4 inches of PVC Sched 40 1-1/2" PIPE
2. PVC Sched 40 1-1/2" CAP SOC (hole drilled in bottom)
3. 1/2" Poly Combination Elbow
4. 1/2" ID x 5/8 OD Nylon hose
5. 1/2" Insert x 1/4" Male Pipe Thread Brass Hose Connector
6. 1/2" Female Thread x Male Garden Hose Thread 1/2" Sediment Faucet, with Flange

**THE PROBLEM**

The problem I am having is going from the PVC 1-1/2" Pipe to the 1/2" Poly Combo Elbow.

I tried drilling a hole into the bottom of the 1-1/2" CAP SOC, and then threading it, but it is nearly impossible to hit the dead centre each time without a lathe, and without a proper tap tool a pain in the buttocks to thread the drilled hole. (I also can't find a proper sized tap in the entire town either. I'm forcing the threading by cramming a 3/4" bolt into it)

Is there something similar to the ABS Dishwasher Bushing that would solve my headache and at the same time replace the PVC 1-1/2" CAP SOC?

Help me... You're my only hope. (Geeky Star Wars reference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They make the same type of bushing that you used before, but in PVC. It would be called an 1 1/2" x 1/2" slip x FIP bushing. "FIP" means female iron pipe.

[image]

This picture is actually 1" FIP, which will be easier to find than 1/2", and also easy to "bush" down to smaller sizes using threaded brass bushings:

[image]

Comment: I went to a plumbing wholesaler and the fella at the counter helped me order one of these: A PVC bushing 1½ spigot x ½ fpt. One that will slip right into the pvc pipe, and has the right sized threads to connect to the elbow. It looked exactly like the one in the photo you posted.

Comment: cool, good luck on your project... I like the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sealing nut that can be bought at almost all local hardware shops.

[image]